# $_POST not running for the form inside PHP script

Tags: php, html

I was making a `form` inside a `PHP` script and when i tried to access a field 
of `form` in the same script it was giving me error **Undefined index**

This is my code:

```
<?php
    $query="SELECT * FROM `vendor_list`";
    $query_run=mysql_query($query);

    if(mysql_num_rows($query_run)>0)
    {
        echo '<form method="POST">';
        echo 'Book name:<input type="text" name="book_name"  size="40"  maxlength="40"><br><br>';
        echo 'Number Of Copies:<input type="text" size="5" name="num_copies" maxlength="2"><br><br>';

        echo '<select name="vendor_email">';
        while($query_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run))
        {
            $laser=$query_row['vendor_name'];
            $email=$query_row['email'];
            echo "<option value='".$email."'>".$laser."</option>";
        }
        echo '</select><br>';
        echo '<input type="submit" value="submit">';
        echo '</form>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'No vendor to display';
    }

    echo $_POST['book_name'];
```

Comment: Make sure you're having the same fields in database i.e vendor_name and email ..

Comment: Please post your table vendor_list structure

Comment: there is no problem with the database, it's working fine ,problem lies in last line **echo $_POST['book_name']** ,which I have taken as a field name in the form

Comment: If the form doesn't exist how can you echo anything from it? also you know that post data is carried to the next request right? So you can't do that. You need to wrap that in an isset or something...epic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE THIS:-

```
    <?php
        $query="SELECT * FROM `vendor_list`";
        $query_run=mysql_query($query);

        if(mysql_num_rows($query_run)>0)
        {
            echo '<form method="POST">';
            echo 'Book name:<input type="text" name="book_name"  size="40"  maxlength="40"><br><br>';
            echo 'Number Of Copies:<input type="text" size="5" name="num_copies" maxlength="2"><br><br>';

            echo '<select name="vendor_email">';
            while($query_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run))
            {
                $laser=$query_row['vendor_name'];
                $email=$query_row['email'];
                echo "<option value='".$email."'>".$laser."</option>";
            }
            echo '</select><br>';
            echo '<input type="submit" value="submit">';
            echo '</form>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'No vendor to display';
        }


if($_POST){
 echo $_POST['book_name'];

}
    ?>
```

Comment: I still would correct the action="" part of the form, instead of leaving it blank/unset.. set the value to the PHP_SELF variable.

Comment: If you will not add any action then by default action will be same page.

Comment: If i am not mistake, older versions if IE have a problem with this.. I can not say for sure, but just always been a little more preventative by forcefully including it. For html4 standards it should at least be set to action=""

Comment: @Mayhem you can leave it blank it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <?php
            $query="SELECT * FROM `vendor_list`";
            $query_run=mysql_query($query);

            if(mysql_num_rows($query_run)>0)
            {
?>
                <form method="POST" action="">
                Book name:<input type="text" name="book_name"  size="40"  maxlength="40"><br><br>
                Number Of Copies:<input type="text" size="5" name="num_copies" maxlength="2"><br><br>

                <select name="vendor_email">
<?php
                while($query_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run))
                {
                    $laser=$query_row['vendor_name'];
                    $email=$query_row['email'];
                    echo "<option value='".$email."'>".$laser."</option>";
                }
?>
                </select><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
                </form>
<?php
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'No vendor to display';
            }


    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))){
     echo $_POST['book_name'];

    }
        ?>
```

Comment: Also you don't need to echo the html part, just end the php tag and put ur html and restart, let me edit the given answer to incorporate that.

Answer (score 0):

Using the below code this will also check if you have a form submission or not, unless this code is a cut/copy paste.. It looks like it will process sections when it should not.. eg the echo post..

Personally i myself will set the action="" to PHP_SELF as many years ago had issues with it, soon this will change once i start using HTML5 when its cross browser enough / older users update their browsers.

Example of processing or showing a post but not both.

```
        echo $_POST['book_name'];
        echo "POST Dump: " . print_r($_POST, true);
    } else {

        // No Form Submission, So we generate the form instead
        // QUERY - data
        $query = "SELECT * FROM 'vendor_list'";
        $query_run = mysql_query($query);

        if(mysql_num_rows($query_run)>0) {
            // FORM - Name/#Copies
            echo '<form method="POST" action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '">';
            echo 'Book name:<input type="text" name="book_name"  size="40"  maxlength="40"><br><br>';
            echo 'Number Of Copies:<input type="text" size="5" name="num_copies" maxlength="2"><br><br>';

            // FORM - Select Vendor
            echo '<select name="vendor_email">';
            while($query_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run))
            {
                $laser=$query_row['vendor_name'];
                $email=$query_row['email'];
                echo "<option value='".$email."'>".$laser."</option>";
            }
            echo '</select><br>';

            // FORM - Submit / Close Form
            echo '<input type="submit" value="submit">';
            echo '</form>';
        } else {
            echo 'No vendor to display';
        }

    }
?>
```

Or using a code that shows the form and processing any $_POST

```
<?php
    // QUERY - data
    $query = "SELECT * FROM 'vendor_list'";
    $query_run = mysql_query($query);

    if(mysql_num_rows($query_run)>0) {
        // FORM - Name/#Copies
        echo '<form method="POST" action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '">';
        echo 'Book name:<input type="text" name="book_name"  size="40"  maxlength="40"><br><br>';
        echo 'Number Of Copies:<input type="text" size="5" name="num_copies" maxlength="2"><br><br>';

        // FORM - Select Vendor
        echo '<select name="vendor_email">';
        while($query_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run))
        {
            $laser=$query_row['vendor_name'];
            $email=$query_row['email'];
            echo "<option value='".$email."'>".$laser."</option>";
        }
        echo '</select><br>';

        // FORM - Submit / Close Form
        echo '<input type="submit" value="submit">';
        echo '</form>';
    } else {
        echo 'No vendor to display';
    }

    if (isset($_POST['book_name'])) {
        echo "<b>Displaying post data</b> <br />";
        echo "Example book: " . $_POST['book_name'] . "<br />";
        echo "POST Dump: <br /><pre>" . print_r($_POST, true) . "</pre>";
    } else {
        echo "Page has not been subitted yet, please select an item";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

## The Clean Way

All the breaks you have in that code are a hot mess...

**Tip** When you are echoing too much HTML just wrap it in an if..else.. like this...

```
<?php
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `vendor_list`";
  $query_run = mysql_query($query);
?>

<?php if(mysql_num_rows($query_run)>0): ?>
  <form method="POST">
    <label for="book_name">Book name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="book_name" id="book_name" size="40"  maxlength="40">
    <label for="book_name"Number Of Copies:</label>
    <input type="text" size="5" name="num_copies" maxlength="2">
    <select name="vendor_email">
      <?php while($query_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)): ?>
          <option value="<?=$query_row['email']?>"><?=$query_row['vendor_name']?></option>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
<?php else: ?>
    <p>No vendor to display</p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php  if (isset($_POST['book_name'])) echo $_POST['book_name']; ?>
```

Comment: Personally i have to disagree, i at times prefer using HEREDOC with escaping variable expressions and so on. Jumping in and out of PHP is to me bad practice of mixing output generation. Good chance later on half to all of the form will be dynamically generated by php anyway.